# How to Captur form values in MVC3 application if we don't have model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a MVC3 application. There are lot of HTML tags inside the view and i'm not using Razor view html tag since we are using sitecore for content management. (We are using simple html tag like `<input type="textbox" id="">`)

And at the end of the page i have button called `GET a Quote`. On click of this button we need to display Loader on the same button, then we have to redirect to another page.

Before redirecting, we need to capture all the form values and we have to calculate quote, i.e, we have to fetch form values in `Controller` method/action.

Can anyone suggest me, which is the best way to do?

As per i know,

1. We can have `Submit` for `GET a Quote`, and we can capture this value in the Controller method using

   [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult(FormCollection form) 
       { 
       }

   But here, how we can display Loader image on the Submit button.
2. We can Make `GET a Quote` as Hyperlink, and we can call the script, that will capture all the form values and then we can pass it to Controller action method.

But here the problem is, some of the fields will be added dynamically. These dynamically added fields will have the Dynamically created `ID`. How we can capture all forms data?

Please suggest.

Comment: As i mentioned, i cant use Model, like @Html.TextboxFor()... Beacuse we are using sitecore for cms.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `name` attribute to your `input` elements:

```
<input type="text" id="someId1" name="someName1" />
<input type="text" id="someId2" name="someName2" />
<input type="text" id="someId3" name="someName3" />
<input type="text" id="someId4" name="someName4" />
```

When an action is called, your `FormsCollection` object will receive all the values, regardless of whether they were dynamically added or not.

As for the loader image, you want to submit the values using ajax. That way you can specify time interval after which an image should appear. Try using:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("YourActionName", 
    new AjaxOptions {
        UpdateTargetId = "elementIdThatReceivesResult",
        Url = Url.Action("YourActionNameForAjaxRequests"),
        LoadingElementId = "IdOfYourLoader",
        LoadingElementDuration = 500 
    })) {
    @* Your input elements and submit. *@
}
```

Comment: Well, considering that you are not using model you will have to rely upon FormsCollection. In MVC 1 (and probably 2 but don't hold my word for version 2), FormsCollection was the default way to retrieve your values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that using ajax and json can help you sending data from a view to a controller.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ Id: Id }),
                success: function (result) { //some code }
            });
```

I use it this way to pass data to a controller without a model.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use model binding, you have to approaches as the following:

1) Get them from the Request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitAction()
{
    var id = Request["id"];
    var value2 = Request["name2"];
    var value3 = Request["name3"];
    // also for other inputs of the form which have name attribute...    
}
```

2) GetThem by means of `FormCollection`

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult SubmitAction(FormCollection frm)
{    
    string id = frm.Get("id");
    string value2 = frm.Get("name2");
    string value3 = frm.Get("name3");
    // also for other inputs of the form which have name attribute...
}
```

Note that the first way gives you objects(the reason I used `var`) so you need to cast them appropriately. However, the second approach gives you strings(the reason I used `string` - just for mention that).

And about the loader image, instead of showing the loader on the submit button itself, I prefer to show it next to the button. To do so, you can add the loader like the following:

```
<img id="imgSpinner" src="..." style="display:none" />
```

Then you can show and hide it through ajax process:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '...',
        type: 'POST',
        // ... other ajax options ...
        beforeSend: function () { $("#imgSpinner").show(); },
        complete: function () { $("#imgSpinner").hide(); }
    });
```